# Can't Check Radio Button with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I was facing issue when try to generate the Radio Buttons.

I have One Radio Button Group which consists of two buttons and will need to checked based on the value from ViewBag in Controller.

However, I was not able to check the radio button. To debug, I added console in the if else statement to make sure that the value is exist and come out with the if else statement and data was working fine, I was able to get true false in the console base on my value. But not sure is my problem or not, the prop() is not making the radio button checked.

```js
var currency = 'USD'; // "@ViewBag.Currency";
console.log(currency);

if (currency == "USD") {
  $("#USD").prop("checked", true);
  $("#SGD").prop("checked", false);
  console.log("true");
} else {
  $("#USD").prop("checked", false);
  $("#SGD").prop("checked", true);
  console.log("false");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
  <input type="radio" id="USD" asp-for="Currency" class="custom-control-input" value="0" required>
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="USD">USD</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
  <input type="radio" id="SGD" asp-for="Currency" class="custom-control-input" value="1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="SGD">SGD</label>
</div>
```

Comment: As provided, your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/3qrnoh9m/  Maybe you have other elements with the same id=USD/id=SGD.   Please provide a *complete* snippet that *demonstrates* the issue - see [mcve].

Comment: Please revise the snippet demo above to show your problem. Note that jQuery questions have little to do with ASP, so that tag and related code should be omitted from your question to avoid needless distraction.